# How to configure log4j2 with to log to application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have been beating my head against this article for the last 90 minutes. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-2x-trace-logs) But I can't get it to work. I feel like there is something about this article that is incomplete. I have added the dependency to the gradle file like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3'
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-logging-log4j2', version: '2.0.+'
}
```

I have added the logger config to the log4j2.xml file like this:

```
<Configuration packages="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.log4j.v2">
    <Appenders>
        <ApplicationInsightsAppender name="aiAppender" instrumentationKey="[<my key goes here>]" />
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="aiAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

After I do this I go and get the instrumentation key from the application-insights view and put it between the brackets above. I have also tried doing it without the brackets. However when I start the app and log it looks as if the log4j2.xml file is not being picked up and does not send data to application-insights. What am I doing wrong? How can I make it so I can log to application insights with log4j2 as indicated in that article?

Comment: Hello @Dan could you please refer this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11acf7f3-563a-4541-b0e3-d81498ed30fb/unable-to-post-log4j2-trace-logs-to-application-insights-using-applicationinsightslogginglog4j2?forum=ApplicationInsights  ,https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/application-insights/app-insights-java-trace-logs.md . May it help

Comment: Hello @AjayKumarGhose-MT thank you for posting but that does not help as that has the same info that the link that i provided. Does thanks anyway.

Comment: @Dan Did you able to resolve this error? If yes, please post your steps.